# Android build error after change compileSdkVersion from 33 to 34

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I'm getting the following error after change compileSdkVersion from  33 to 34.
The project itself forced me to make this update and I can't build the project anymore

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was update android gradle to 7.5.1 and AGP_version