# Error after changing app's compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

My app working well until I changed the `compileSdkVersion 34` and the `targetSdkVersion 34`.
I am getting the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-osx Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

I have tried the following:

1. Invalid Caches/Restart
2. Change the version of buildTools
3. Clean project
4. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68430992/12143067)
5. Editted the line in the gradle.properties file:`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m`
6. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61983831/12143067) but the app is not separated into modules
7. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76856741/12143067) to upgrade to gradle-8.3 but I got a new error:
   `Failed to notify dependency resolution listener. org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencySubstitutions$Substitution.with(Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/component/ComponentSelector;)V`

I was previously using `targetSdkVersion 30` and `compileSdkVersion 33` but **Google Play requires that apps target API level 31 or higher** and I need to publish an update to Google Play.

`build.gradle (:app)`:

```
plugins {

    id 'com.android.application'

    // Add the Google services Gradle plugin
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com..."
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 10
        versionName "10.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by changing the gradle plugin version in project level build.gradle file.

I changed from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
```

I also had to update my distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties file to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip`

If you are using any maven based url to fetch any library, also make sure that your url is HTTPS and not HTTP.